# Is there any solution to integrate rasa nlu with gpt-j?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, rasa, rasa-nlu

I want to know is there any source like website or solution to integrate gpt-j. I have tried the LanguageModelFeaturizer component in the config file and also trying to add the api key to the action.py file. Currently, I'm working on the transformers model GPT-J integration with Rasa NLU.

```
import openai
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
 
def gptj(text):
  api_key = "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"
   response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="gpt-j",
    # engine="ada",
    prompt="\n\n" + text,
    temperature=0,
    logprobs=10,
    max_tokens=150,
    top_p=0,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=[" \n\n"]
    )
   return response ['choices'][0]['text']

# class ActionHelloWorld(Action):

#     def name(self) -> Text:
#         return "action_hello_world"

#     def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
#             tracker: Tracker,
#             domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
#
#         dispatcher.utter_message(text="Hello World!")
#
#         return []
# 
  class ActionDefaultFallback(Action):
      
       def init(self):
         #  self.gptj = gptj()
           super()._init_()

       def name(self) -> Text:
           return "action_default_fallback"

       async def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
           query = tracker.latest_message['text']
           dispatcher.utter_message(text=gptj(query))

           return [UserUtteranceReverted()]
```

The LanguageModelFeaturizer component does not have the gpt-j model. The action python file does not work while I run the "rasa run actions" command in the terminal it kept running and there are no responds but When I run "rasa train" and "rasa shell", it run and works normally without the gpt-j trained on it.

```
(rasa_flow) C:\Users\User\Desktop\RASA INIT>rasa run actions
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\rasa_flow\lib\site-packages\sanic_cors\extension.py:39: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  SANIC_VERSION = LooseVersion(sanic_version)
2022-11-25 14:47:47 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2022-11-25 14:47:48 INFO     rasa_sdk.executor  - Registered function for 'action_default_fallback'.
2022-11-25 14:47:48 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running on http://0.0.0.0:5055
```

P.s I don't think that the actions.py file will work. Probably, I will create a separate python file for the api to work.(Just a speculation)

Anyway, is there a possible way to integrate Rasa NLU with GPT-J?